# Haskell function that checks if a word contains in binary tree

Tags: haskell

I have to write a function is Haskell that checks if a word contains in binary tree. The only requirement is that the last symbol of the word, should be a leaf of the tree.

Here is the tree I got:

```
t1 :: BTree Char 
t1 = Node 'a'   (Node 'c'   (Node 'f' Empty Empty) 
                            (Node 'd' Empty Empty)) 
                (Node 'b' Empty 
                            (Node 'e' Empty Empty))
```

And here is what I wrote, but its only for Tree with one element:

```
containsWord :: BTree Char -> String -> Bool
containsWord Empty _ = False
containsWord (Node v Empty Empty) ch 
|v == ch    = True
|otherwise  = False
```

I don't know how to continue.
Here are two examples:

```
containsWord t1 "acd" → True
containsWord t1 "ac" → False
```

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154351/i-have-the-following-binary-tree-data-btree-a-empty-node-a-btree-a-btree

Answer (score 1):

The first problem here is that the statement `v == ch` will not compile because `v` is a `Char` and `ch` is a `String`. The second guard should therefore be (note also that your guards are not necessary, since `v == ch` is already the value you need):

```
containsWord (Node v Empty Empty) [ch] = v == ch
```

Given this fix, what patters are now not matched? You need to match on non-leaf nodes and strings longer than one character. So you should think about what definitions fit with these three patterns:

```
containsWord _            []
containsWord (Node v l r) (ch : s)
```

The first one is the case of matching any node against an empty string. Given your problem statement above, this should never be true, thus:

```
containsWord _ [] = False
```

The second one is the primary recursive case of your function. Check if the current node's value matches the first character, then check if either subtree matches the rest of the string.

```
containsWord (Node v l r) s@(ch : rs) =
    | ch == v   = containsWord l rs || containsWord r rs
    | otherwise = containsWord l  s || containsWord r  s
```

Now I would suggest that `containsWord Empty ""` should be `True`. If that's the case, you need to add another pattern to the beginning:

```
containsWord Empty [] = True
```

In this case, the first pattern we discussed (`containsWord (Node v Empty Empty) [ch]`) is actually unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you, but this works only for words, which are with max lenght for the tree. The function should also works with 2 and 1 letter words, whose last letter is in leaf. For example "cd" and ''d" should return True.

Comment: Right. I adjusted one of the cases to fix that.

Comment: You forgot to remove the "=", but now it says "Non-exhaustive patterns in function containsWord"

Comment: What pattern does it say isn't matched?

Comment: It gaves this row as a problem `| otherwise = containsWord l  s || containsWord r  s`